# How can I change the style of UITabBar?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to make UITabBar in such a way that it will have 5 items and the middle one will be come out of the tab bar. How can I get these done?

I can't share my code. What I am doing in my code I can describe.

In my Delegate.m file I am creating one UITabBarController and created 5 UIViewControllers. For each tabItem I kept one View Controller and kept them in an Array and added them to my tabbar.viewControllers.

Comment: This question probably wasn't ever answerable, since it does not feature code or illustrative images. I will try to put it on hold for now.